# Chrome or chromium can not use ibus

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, ibus

I have ibus works fine in every apps (firefox, text editor) but not chromium or chrome

After figured it out I will post here if someone else had a same problem

Mine is ubuntu 18.04, zsh shell.

Credit to https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=173675

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to zshrc or bashrc...

```
#ibus
export GTK_IM_MODULE=xim #Fix for Chrome
export QT_IM_MODULE=xim #Not sure if this works or not, but whatever
export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
```

after that `source ~/.zshrc`

start chrome frome command line and enjoy

Comment: sadly doesn't seem to work for me with Chrome on Wayland :-(

Comment: Mine is ibus 1.5.17, xfce 4.12, `chrome Version 105.0.5195.102 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 18.04 (64-bit) `

Did you try to logout?

Comment: I'm on 108 now, but I think the problem is that I'm using Wayland, not X11.

Comment: This works for me, while starting browsers from desktop icon does not work though. `Exec=env GTK_IM_MODULE=xim XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus /usr/bin/microsoft-edge`

Comment: Di anyone figure out how to make the .desktop icon work?

Comment: you can write a shell then lauch from .desktop?

Answer (score 0):

> export GTK_IM_MODULE=xim #Fix for Chrome

This **does not work on GNOME 45 Wayland** (tested on Manjaro Linux, and Ubuntu ships Wayland by default now too IIRC) as of 2023 and Chromium 119.

What does work is starting Chromium/Chrome in GTK4 mode:

```sh
chromium --gtk-version=4
```

Solution from `u/tinywrkb` in comments there: https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/sc0oxo/ibus_japanese_input_not_working_in_google_chrome/

It'd be best add the flag permanently to the chrome launch config, but I forgot where it was (somebody help please?) and there is no flag for the GTK version in `chrome://flags/`.

A worse solution (but one I know) is to modify the `chromium.desktop` file, e.g. with `sed` or `awk` since there may be many launch options (Incognito mode and such). Example using `sed`, run with ROOT priveleges (`sudo`, `su`, `doas` etc.):

```
sed -i.bak 's/Exec\=\/usr\/bin\/chromium/Exec\=\/usr\/bin\/chromium --gtk-version=4/g' /usr/share/applications/chromium.desktop
```

Note 1: The `-i.bak` options creates `chromium.desktop.bak` backup file. Remove it with `rm -v /usr/share/applications/chromium.desktop.bak` (run with ROOT privilieges).
Note 2: Command string escaped to POSIX standard as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076026 
Note 3: The `.desktop` file may and probably will get overwritten next time Chromium gets updated on your system and you'll have to re-run this command (which is why it's worse than aforementioned).

P.S. This `--gtk-version=4` option also fixed the same input issue for VSCodium, and may work for other Electron-based apps.
P.P.S. This answer will probably become obsolete once GTK5 is out or Chromium adopts GTK4 as standard version.
P.P.P.S. Only tested on Manjaro Linux, it SHOULD work on Ubuntu (tried to be as XDG standards compliant as possible) but **someone please verify and confirm in the comments**.

Comment: Doesn't work on ubuntu 22.04 with chromium or edge or plain chrome, using ozone platform. On VSCode from MS, it just crash.